# Loopback Passport Cookie issue with Passport setting prefix of s%3A

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, loopbackjs

Not sure where the problem is coming from, so I don't know what to give. Cookie is being stored with a s%3A prefix ( s: decoded. )

Immediate thoughts? more information can be provided...

Comment: seems like putting cookie-parser adds the extra prefix on there, removing cookie-parser lets me get the access token... ughh....

Comment: seems like its from the use of the prebuild cookie signature.. but don't think it should make a difference, going to test...

Comment: really wish loopback had more documentation :/ hmm.. going to find out how to incorporate this auth for front end.

Comment: got this working, although trying to figure out how to use loopback correctly to take current logged in user. Trying to understand rolls

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Looks like it was a common issue. The example near the bottom of this thread solved it: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/issues/26